# I have a issue with chart.js, php and infomix database?

Tags: php, pdo, chart.js, informix

Helloi have a problem with chart.js, php and informix database.

first i test the script with easy mysql database and they works good.

but when im using informix database with pdo he show me on chart label undefined.

=> my data.php (for connection to database) :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');


$db=new pdo("informix:host=uccxpub;service=1504;database=db_cra;server=uccxpub_uccx;protocol=onsoctcp;EnableScrollabelCursors=1;client_local=en_US.UTF8;db_locale=en_US.UTF8","uccxwallboard","cisco2016"
) or die("Impossible de se connecter !!!");


$sql0 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM  RtCSQsSummary where CSQName = 'BMCE BANK'"); 

/*$stmt = $db->prepare($sql0);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
*/

$result = $db->query($sql0);
//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

//now print the data


print json_encode($data);
?>
```

=> the output of data.php :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0YNY.png)

=> my bargraph.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "../data.php",
        method: "GET",


        success: function(data) {

            console.log(data);
            var startdatetime = [];
            var loggedInAgents = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                startdatetime.push("startdatetime " + data[i].startdatetime);
                loggedInAgents.push(data[i].loggedInAgents);
            }


            var chartdata  {
                labels: startdatetime,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label: 'loggedInAgents',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: loggedInAgents,
                    }
                ]
            };


            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

=> the output :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFBHx.png)
=> my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ChartJS - BarGraph</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #chart-container {
                width: 640px;
                height: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart-container">
            <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
        </div>

        <!-- javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bargraph.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

!! the bar graph not show me callshandled undefinded ..

test with mysql database :

=> data.php :

```
<?php
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root123');
define('DB_NAME', 'mydb');

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT playerid, score FROM score ORDER BY playerid");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

=>bargraph.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var player = [];
            var score = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                player.push("Player " + data[i].playerid);
                score.push(data[i].score);
            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: player,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label: 'Player Score',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: score
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

=> index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ChartJS - BarGraph</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #chart-container {
                width: 640px;
                height: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart-container">
            <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
        </div>

        <!-- javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bargraph.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

hes work so fine.

Comment: Thankyou. Also FYI please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest - you're talking to volunteers here giving their free time. Saying it's a very urgent problem might imply your time is more valuable than that of the people answering questions. It's not a good way to encourage people to help you.

Comment: Anyway you claim it stops working when you changed the database. But your picture of the output looks like valid JSON. So it's clearly producing some results. have you tried comparing the output produced when connected to mySQL, and the output produced when connected to informix, and seeing what the difference is? Chart.js doesn't care what database you used, it only cares about the JSON it receives.

Comment: @ADyson i correct  my question, so about using mysql i create the same table of informix and he works good. when i change it to informix database he dosnt work again.

Comment: yes you've already said that in the question. You need to dig deeper - see my above comment. I can only see the output from the informix version, I can't see the output from the mysql version. As I said, chart.js doesn't know you changed the database, all it knows about is your JSON. So if changing the database (and any related code) produces a problem, then you first need to compare the JSON produced by them to see if there's a difference. If there is, then you need to work out what caused the difference, whether it's different code or different data. This is just simple debugging technique

Comment: I put the source code for mysql database in the end.

Comment: ok so "changing the database" actually means running a completely different query with a completely different dataset? Changing from mysql to informix is not the issue, it's that you're using totally different data. Talk about a total red herring...why didn't you explain that? Almost all the code is different, even the JavaScript. You completely failed to give sufficient detail.

Comment: so now all you have to do is make sure your JSON fits the requirements for using with chartJS. The fact it comes from informix or mysql is irrelevant. What _is_ relevant is the format and content of the data compared with the chartJS spec. I don't know that plugin (I found the question due to the php tag), but presumably you can check the documentation to see what is expected and then make sure your data output is correct in respect to that. Also we don't know what you want your final chart to look like anyway, so it's hard to relate the data to anything meaningful

Comment: However I do notice one thing - your JSON produces all the names in upper-case. Then in your Javascript to try to access the properties in camel-case (i.e. upper and lower-case). But JavaScript is case-sensitive. So perhaps it can't read these properties? Have you even debugged it? Step through your JS code, check your console for errors etc. I think getting the property names right will help a lot.

Comment: im not understand well but my goal is to show the data from the database in a line chart or bar or pie chart with any whay you sugeste to me ..

Comment: how can i check the console or if i can use sme php code to show my the logs ?

Comment: As ADyson said before, the "label undefined" error is because the Informix PDO driver returns the columns name in upper-case and the JS code expects the data in lower-case.  Try changing it to upper-case. e.g: "data[i].STARTDATETIME" instead of "data[i].startdatetime" and 
"data[i].LOGGEDINAGENTS" instead of "data[i].loggedinagents" in your 'bargraph.js'

Comment: @J_S like that : for(var i in data) {
                startdatetime.push("startdatetime " + "data[i].STARTDATETIME" instead of "data[i].startdatetime");
                loggedInAgents.push( "data[i].LOGGEDINAGENTS" instead of "data[i].loggedinagents");
            }

Comment: yeap, that will pass something like "startdatetime 2018-06-19,startdatetime 2018-06-18 ....." to the bargraph function rather than "startdatetime undefined,startdatetime undefined....".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code (with some minor fixes) on my Linux box. I can display the bar graph with some simple test data from an Informix database:

html page:

```
informix@irk:/var/www/html# cat test.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ChartJS - BarGraph</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #chart-container {
                width: 640px;
                height: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart-container">
            <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
        </div>

        <!-- javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://irk/b.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
informix@irk:/var/www/html#
```

javascript:

```
informix@irk:/var/www/html# cat b.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://irk/data.php",
        method: "GET",

        success: function(data) {

    var obj=JSON.parse(data);
    data=obj;
            var startdatetime = [];
            var loggedInAgents = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                startdatetime.push( data[i].STARTDATETIME);
                loggedInAgents.push(data[i].LOGGEDINAGENTS);
            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: startdatetime,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label: 'loggedInAgents',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: loggedInAgents 
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
informix@irk:/var/www/html#
```

php script getting the data from Informix:

```
informix@irk:/var/www/html# cat data.php
<?php

$db=new pdo("informix:database=enusutf8;server=irk1210;CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8;DB_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8","informix","testpwd") or die("Impossible de se connecter !!!");

$sql0 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM  RtCSQsSummary where CSQName = 'BMCE BANK'"); 

$result = $db->query($sql0);
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

print json_encode($data);
?>

informix@irk:/var/www/html#
```

In addition to the uppercase/lowercase mentioned before, the JSON data the JS function gets
has to be parse before it can be used. Otherwise you will get "undefied" values in the 'for(var i in data)' loop, no matter what case you used.